# Meaning of "Industry Puzzled"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not a native speaker and I have a bit of trouble with understanding the meaning of the term *Industry Puzzled* in a newspaper headline.

Here is an example I found that uses the term:

> Biodiesel **Industry Puzzled** By Loosening Of Alternative Fuel Standard

Can anyone explain to me its meaning in simple English?

Comment: Newspapers Headlines are usually very concise and words are often omitted.  In this case,  "The biodiesel industry is puzzled by..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misreading of a noun plus a verb as being some sort of term-of-art phrase with a special meaning of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it means that those who are involved in the Biodiesel Industry cannot understand either the policy which motivates the Government/ Ministry/ Department to make changes in the standard, or is calculating unpredictable effects on cost and sales.

> . http://www.thefreedictionary.com/puzzled
>   **puzzled** (adjective)
>   - - filled with bewilderment; at a loss, nonplused, perplexed